# Pyro4 and plain old data objects

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyro4

I have an object which I expose with Pyro4 and which returns a POD object:

```
import Pyro4

@Pyro4.expose
class POD:
    def __init__(self):
        self.a = 1

@Pyro4.expose
class Source:
    def get(self):
        p = POD()
        daemon.register(p)
        return p

daemon = Pyro4.daemon()
ns = Pyro4.locateNS()
uri = daemon.register(Source)
ns.register('test_obj', uri)
daemon.requestLoop()
```

But when I try to retrieve this object like this:

```
import Pyro4
s = Pyro4.Proxy('PYRONAME:test_obj')
o = s.get()
print(o.a)
```

I get an exception like this:

```
Pyro4.errors.PyroError: remote object doesn't expose any methods or attributes. Did you forget setting @expose on them?
```

Is there some way to return POD objects and use their fields, or do I need to expose these fields through methods or properties?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the documentation for the server side, section [Creating a Pyro class and exposing its methods and properties](http://pyro4.readthedocs.io/en/latest/servercode.html#creating-a-pyro-class-and-exposing-its-methods-and-properties):

> You can’t expose attributes directly. It is required to provide a `@property` for them and decorate that with `@expose`, if you want to provide a remotely accessible attribute.

So you need to change the `POD` class to:

```
@Pyro4.expose
class POD:
    def __init__(self):
        self._a = 1

    @property
    def a(self):
        return self._a

    # Only necessary when setting the property should be possible.
    @a.setter
    def a(self, value):
        self._a = value
```

Comment: You're linking to the old documentation on Pythonhosted.org, that unfortunately can't be updated any longer as far as I am aware. The documentation has been moved to Readthedocs.io instead  http://pyro4.readthedocs.io/en/latest/servercode.html#creating-a-pyro-class-and-exposing-its-methods-and-properties